# Composer memory limit docker

Tags: php, symfony, docker, docker-compose, composer-php

I have a problem with **composer install** on docker. This is my **docker-compose** file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 433:433
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    links:
      - php-fmp
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network

  php-fmp:
    build: docker/php-fmp
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=goexpress
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=docker
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I try to execute **docker-compose run php-fmp composer install** it starts after some minutes it shows **memory limit xxxxxxxxx**. I have tried also **memory_limit=-1**.

**My laptop memory: 6GB.**

In another pc it works perfect.

Before upgrade of memory it has worked. Memory before was 4GB now it is 6GB. The project that I want to run is symfony.

Comment: How have you set your memory limit?
If you run the following command in you php-fpm container, what does it return?  
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"  

btw why is your container named «php-fmp» instead of «php-fpm»?

Answer (score 14):

Composer has its own `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT` environment variable, but uses php.ini's `memory_limit` by default when its own variable is not set. https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-memory-limit

With Docker Compose you will need to pass `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT` as an environment variable to the container where Composer is installed. Your docker-compose.yml file would look like this:

```
services:

  php-fmp: //the name of your container (as per your question)

    environment:
      - COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 //-1 means unlimited
```

This environment variable would be taken into account every time you run Composer with docker-compose:

```
docker-compose exec php-fmp composer [your composer command]
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer install` try `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install`. Composer starts a new php process, that does not adhere to the setting you provide and it might even override the config (I'm not a 100% sure about that).

If that still does not help open the preferences for Docker (by clicking on the icon in the task bar) under the Advanced tab you can specify how many cores and how much memory docker is allowed to consume. I think the default is 2GB and you might want to change that to e.g. 4GB.